# Free periodical satellite/aerial imagery

Tags: remote-sensing, agriculture, satellites, forest

There is a company called [Planet Labs](https://www.planet.com/) which sells daily satellite imagery covering the whole globe that can be used for various research  like agriculture, forestry etc. I wonder if there is a free equivalent of Planet Labs that offers periodically captured satellite or aerial imagery with decent resolution possibly on global scale or at least on regional scale (whole country). Do maybe NASA or ESA offer something periodical with decent coverage and resolution?

Comment: Try https://worldview.earthdata.nasa.gov/ and you can download Sentinel data and try to produce some high quality images using an appropriate python package.

Comment: check out [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) That might (or might not!) be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

There are a wide ranging of publically available satellite images with different spatial and temporal resolutions. Notably Landsat (`https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/`) and Sentinel (`https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home`) come to mind.
If you are interested in analysing remote sensing products at a global or regional scale, Google Earth Engine (`https://developers.google.com/earth-engine`) may be a useful tool for you. GEE can directly access Landsat and Sentinel products at no cost to the user.

I hope this information is of use to you.

Comment: I went to the earth-engine site and registered myself. I cannot seem to download a single image

Comment: I go here https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY and there is no download link whatsoever

Comment: You cannot download an image or any data from GEE directly, you need to write code to export any data. Have a look at the guides to GEE (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides) and the export guides in particular (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-todrive?hl=en).

If you want to download satellite images directly without GEE use the Landsat and Sentinel websites instead.

Comment: yes thanks for your comment. I did try the sentinel coperncus hub but the volume of data was humongous (880 MB) that didn't really interest me. But you are right. If we need the best quality satelite images some time has to be investd up front